# passing parameters to power bi filter programmatically from asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powerbi-embedded

I have developed a powerBI report and deployed the same in Workspace.
From PowerBI interface I viewed the report and am able to add filter like this: 
filter=tablename~2Fcolumnname eq 4
The condition is working fine from the interface. But, when I add filter condition in the code of my asp.ner MVC application, filter does not work.

The condition is working fine from the interface. 
But, when I add filter condition in the code of my asp.ner MVC application, filter does not work.

My sample code:

```
var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(ApiUrl), tokenCredentials);
var reports = await client.Reports.GetReportsInGroupAsync(WorkspaceId);
report = reports.Value.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == "aa07v254-8t46-2387-4k53-2725y90n3456");

report.EmbedUrl = report.EmbedUrl + "?filter=tablename/columnname%20eq%204";
```

Please help me diagnose, why the filter is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to change the embed url, instead try to use the following example:

```
// Build the filter you want to use. For more information, See Constructing
// Filters in https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Filters.
const filter = {
    $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#basic",
    target: {
        table: "Geo",
        column: "Region"
    },
    operator: "In",
    values: ["West"]
};

// Get a reference to the embedded report HTML element
var embedContainer = $('#embedContainer')[0];

// Get a reference to the embedded report.
report = powerbi.get(embedContainer);

// Set the filter for the report.
// Pay attention that setFilters receives an array.
report.setFilters([filter])
    .then(function () {
        Log.logText("Report filter was set.");
    })
    .catch(function (errors) {
        Log.log(errors);
    });
```